# Why Runtime error if input array element are parsed to integer altogether in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string-parsing

I was working on [counting sort1](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/countingsort1) problem on hackerrank. I am using JavaScript to solve the problem.

Standard input is providing a number and an array which I was reading like this

```
var inp = input.split('\n')  

var n = parseInt(inp[0]);  //Number of elements
var ar = inp[1].split(' ').map(function(item){
    return parseInt(item);
});   //Array of numbers.
```

I was using above code in almost all of my solutions, it always worked.
Then I process the above array `ar` in `for` loop which is giving runtime error in one of the test cases(last testcase).

```
for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   var number = ar[i];
   //more code
}
```

But if I don't parse elements of the array using map function but parse them later in for loop, one by one, I don't get any error.

```
var ar = in[1].split(' ');   //Array of numbers in string format

for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   var number = parseInt(ar[i]);
   //more code
}
```

Can Anyone explain Why?

Comment: Can you pack your case in a standalone executable snippet? What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Your last snippet works, right ?

Comment: @gaurang yes. The second snippet works.

Comment: @sabof on submitting it's showing `Runtime error`, nothig else.

Comment: @kushdilip no worries, I understood how hackerrank is supposed to be working.

Comment: @sabof lol, I didn't mean that.. I just don't want to spend my hackos on such silly things..

Comment: Finally downloaded the 4th test case. The size of array is 10000. Running code with this data gives below error 

`FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_2 Allocation failed - process out of memory`

I guess, `map` is not able to handle this much amount of data due to large number of callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

`in` is a keyword, and you are trying to use it as a variable. I'm not sure why it says "Runtime Error", since this is actually a parsing error. Once renamed to something else, I could run the first two paragraphs error-free.

Comment: I was actually using `inp` as the variable name not `in`.. I have updated the question.

Comment: @kushdilip and as I've said, I can no longer reproduce your error.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I remember having on Hackerrank that the `.split()` method often gave an empty string (`""`) as the last element of the array. Probably that's why you failed on the last test case.

Make your logic like:

```
if(arr[i] !== "") 
    // perform operations
else 
    break;
```

Also, you can't use `in` as a identifier because it is a reserved keyword.

Comment: I don't think `.split()` is a problem here... code worked after removing `.map()`. 
I was actually using `inp` as the variable name not `in`.. I have updated the question.

Comment: @kushdilip That is strange. Try adding some more `console.log`s to your code, and run it locally with some of your own sample tests. Maybe, it gave RunTime Error because your code couldn't handle something. Some names of ReferenceErrors are [given here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dk3k160(v=vs.94).aspx)

Comment: Thanks @gaurang . I'll try testing it locally.